# Read file Scanner Method. then make array list in main

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am new to java and I am having trouble with this. I need to read a txt file full of integers in a method and then I am supposed to call it in the main to make an ArrayList. I can't seem to figure it out.

this is what i have.

```
public class num {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        list=  getFile();
        System.out.println("numbers are: " + list);
    }

    public static void getFile() {

        try {
            Scanner read = new Scanner(new File("numbers.txt"));

            do {
                int line = read.nextInt();
            }while (read.hasNext());

        } catch (FileNotFoundException fnf) {
            System.out.println("File was not found");
        }

        return line;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to return something from the method so it shouldn't be `void` (Think about what you need it to return. You'll want to do something like `ArrayList<Integer> list = getFile();` in the main)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class num {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    getFile(list);
System.out.println("numbers are: " + list);
}

public static void getFile(ArrayList<Integer> list) {


    try {
        Scanner read = new Scanner(new File("numbers.txt"));

        do {
        list.add(read.nextInt());


        }while (read.hasNext());



    } catch (FileNotFoundException fnf) {
        System.out.println("File was not found");
    }

}
```

Basically, your `getFile()` method is of type void so it won't return anything. So, you would need to pass your list as a parameter inside this method and then mutate that list. The changes you can then view in your main method.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the return type of your method to List and store each nextInt in a local ArrayList and you must return the local list at the end !

```
public class num {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> list = getFile();
        list.forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    public static List<Integer> getFile() {
        List res = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        try {
            Scanner read = new Scanner(new File("numbers.txt"));
            do {
                res.add(read.nextInt());
            }while (read.hasNext());
        } catch (FileNotFoundException fnf) {
            System.out.println("File was not found");
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Please take a look at the code here - https://gist.github.com/ajinkya-mundankar/c2dcbf9dd95d0aa214c9d5d4ece80061